# Javascript calculate tax and total price

Tags: javascript, html

I'm facing a little issue in calculating total price and tax per product.
I also made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wk4dpfLt/1/

This is a simplified piece of code of my actual code:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>Product</td>
       <td>Prijs</td>
       <td>BTW</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text'  value='Product1' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='p1' value='10' name='prijs' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='bh1' value='21' name='btw_hoog' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' value='Product2' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='p2' value='10' name='prijs' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='bh2' value='21' name='btw_hoog' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' value='Product3' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='p3' value='10' name='prijs' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='bl1' value='6' name='btw_laag' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' value='Product4' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='p4' value='10' name='prijs' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='bl2' value='6' name='btw_laag' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button id='myBtn'>Bereken</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Totaal:</td>
        <td><input type='text' value='' id='totaalprijs' class='totaalprijs' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Totaal BTW Laag:</td>
        <td><input type='text' value='' id='totaalbtwlaag_input' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Totaal BTW Hoog:</td>
        <td><input type='text' value='' id='totaalbtwhoog' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Totaal incl. BTW:</td>
        <td><input type='text' value='' class='totaalinc' /></td>
    </tr>
```

In this piece I have 4 rows of products.
Product = name of the product, Prijs is the prize of the product and BTW is the tax.
Now basically what I try to achieve is to fill the 4 rows Totaal, BTW Laag , Totaal BTW Hoog and Totaal incl. BTW when I click on the button.

Totaal is the total sum of prizes. I got this working.
Totaal BTW Laag is the value of id bl which is 6. 6 is in procent, so I tried (6 / 100) * prize, but this isn't working..

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
This is my javascript:

```
function getPrijs()
 {
     var prijzenCount = document.getElementsByName("prijs");
     var total = 0;
         var id= '';
     for(var i = 0; i < prijzenCount.length; i++)
     {
         id = "p"+(i+1);
         total = total +  parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
     }



    document.getElementById('totaalprijs').value = total;

     calcBtwLaag();

 }

function calcBtwLaag()
{

   var btwlaagCount = document.getElementsByName("btw_laag");
     var total = 0;
         var id= '';
         var prijsid = '';
     for(var i = 0; i < btwlaagCount.length; i++)
     {
         id = "bl"+(i+1);
         prijsid = "prijs_laag_"+(i+1);

         if(isNaN(prijsid)) {
             document.getElementsByName(prijsid).value = 0;
             var prijsvalue = parseInt(document.getElementsByName(prijsid).value);
             var btw_laag_procent = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
             var btw_laag_result = (btw_laag_procent / 100) * prijs;
             alert(btw_laag_result);

             total = total +  parseInt(btw_laag_result);
         }
     }



    document.getElementById('totaalbtwlaag_input').value = total;
     return total;
}

function test()
{
 alert(document.getElementById('b3').value);   
}

myBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  getPrijs();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing closing parenthesis :

```
if (!isNaN(prijsid)) {
     note this ----^
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using floats, rather than ints. 6/100 = 0 if they are integers.

```
 var btw_laag_procent = parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).value);
             var btw_laag_result = (btw_laag_procent / 100.0) * parseFloat(prijs);
```

Answer (score 2):

Some issues

- Syntax error in `if (!isNaN(prijsvalue) {` missing a `)`. It should be `if (!isNaN(prijsid)) {`
- The check with the `isNaN` is checking against the name of the element, and not its value.
  You should get its value first and check that (*also note that when using `getElementsByName` you get a collection, so you need to access its elements as an array. Use `[0]` to get the first element even if there is only one.*)

  ```
  prijsid = "prijs_laag_" + (i + 1);
  prijsvalue = parseInt(document.getElementsByName(prijsid)[0].value,10);

  if (!isNaN(prijsvalue)) {
  ```

  - For the calculation just do `(btw_laag_procent * prijsvalue) / 100`

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/wk4dpfLt/3/